# How to install NetBackup 8.0 Client on Ubuntu 16

Tags: server, client

Sorry if question was already answered, I searched it but unable to find it.

What I am looking for a step by step (in layman terms) steps to install NetBackup 8.0 Client on Ubuntu 16.

I found few guides online but those are for older versions and clients and not working on version 16.

I have the Client file, extracted and copied over to server, followed the commands available online but still doing nothing

Support at their forums are useless...

Please guide me.

Thanks

Comment: I have the same question/issue. Still googling....